# Merge 2 dataframes using <> condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two `DataFrame` objects:

- `df1`: `columns = [a, b, c]`
- `df2`: `columns  = [d, e]`

I want to merge `df1` with `df2` using the equivalent of `sql` in `pandas`:

```
select * from df1 inner join df2 on df1.b=df2.e and df1.b <> df2.d and df1.c = 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following sequence of steps should get you there:

```
df1 = df[df1.c==0]
merged = df1.merge(df2, left_on='b', right_on='e')
merge = merged[merged.b != merged.d]
```